# Symphony does not validate html form

Tags: xslt, symphony-cms

I am trying to add this to one of my templates (main.xls) but for some reason it does not validate. Any idea why?

```
<form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLeadencoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
    <input type=hidden name="oid" value="00Db0000000N">
    <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://www.mywebsite.com/cheers/refer=test">
    <label for="first_name">First Name</label><input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>
    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label><input  id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>
    <label for="email">Email</label><input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" /><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The form in question has a few issues a validator should identify for you:

- unclosed tags
- non-quoted attribute values

You need to be using well-formed XHTML in a template.